# Си - вывод на экран числа с указанной точностью

Tags: c

Возможно ли вывести на экран число с указанной точностью, но точность эту вводит сам пользователь.

Как подобное можно реализовать?

Comment: [man fprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)

Comment: Что такое "точность" в вашем случае? Количество значащих цифр? Или количество знаков после запятой?

Comment: @AnT,количество знаков после запятой

Answer (score 4):

Все очень просто - для таких случаев есть [спецификатор `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) вместо конкретных указаний ширины и точности. Вот [простенький пример](https://ideone.com/emK80z):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279;
    for(int w = 5; w < 20; ++w)
    {
        for(int p = 1; p < w; ++p)
        {
            printf("w = %2d p = %2d  pi = %*.*lf\n",w,p,w,p,pi);
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, идея понятна?

Вывод программы следующий:

```
w =  5 p =  1  pi =   3.1
w =  5 p =  2  pi =  3.14
w =  5 p =  3  pi = 3.142
w =  5 p =  4  pi = 3.1416

...

w = 17 p =  5  pi =           3.14159
w = 17 p =  6  pi =          3.141593
w = 17 p =  7  pi =         3.1415927

...

w = 19 p = 15  pi =   3.141592653589793
w = 19 p = 16  pi =  3.1415926535897931
w = 19 p = 17  pi = 3.14159265358979312
w = 19 p = 18  pi = 3.141592653589793116
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned width, precision;
    int number = 256;
    double weight = 242.5;

    printf("What field width?\n");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("The number is :%*d:\n", width, number);
    printf("Now enter a width and a precision:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &width, &precision);
    printf("Weight = %*.*f\n", width, precision, weight);
    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    float x;
    int a,b;
    char fmt[255];

    printf("Введи общую ширину поля: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if ( (a<3) || (a>30) ) {
        printf("Недопустимая ширина поля: %d\n", a);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Введи количество знаков после запятой: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if ( (b<0) || (b>28) ) {
        printf("Недопустимое количество знаков после запятой: %d\n", b);
        return -1;
    }

    sprintf(fmt, "\"%%%d.%df\\n\"", a,b);
    printf("Строка форматирования: %s\n", fmt);

    x = 10.0/3.0;
    printf("Печать по строке форматирования:\n");
    printf(fmt, x);

}
```

Итоговую выдачу специально "обернул" в кавычки, что бы была видна ширина поля.

Comment: "Зачем просто, если можно сложно" - не проще ли сразу использовать `*`?